# Closed form for 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6,

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for a closed form to the sequence $$1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6...$$ According to wolfram alpha the generating function is $$\frac{1+x^{2}+x^{4}}{1-x-x^{7}+x^{8}}$$ but I cannot figure out how to turn this into a closed form as when differentiating (to make a power series) the terms get very complicated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How exactly is the sequence determined? Which numbers are repeated three times, and which ones two times?

Comment: Every multiple of three occurs three times

Comment: Have you tried [OEIS](https://oeis.org/)?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A057357

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the first term corresponds to $n=0$, one formula is $a_n = \biggl\lfloor \dfrac{3n+9}7 \biggr\rfloor$.

If you want a solution without floor or ceiling functions, you'll want to consider $a_n - \frac{3n}7$, which is a periodic function with period $7$ and thus can be written as a linear combination of the seven functions $e^{2\pi k n/7}$ $(0\le k\le 6)$.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the generating function you provided, I assume the sequence is given by $$a_n = \left\lceil \frac{3}{7} n \right\rceil, \quad n \in \{1, 2, \ldots \}.$$

An alternative formulation of this sequence is

$$a_{7k + m} = 3k + \lceil m/2 \rceil,$$ where $k \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$ is the quotient of $n$ divided by $7$, and $m \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 6\}$ is the remainder of $n$ divided by $7$.

The second form is particularly amenable to calculating the ordinary generating function, since $$\begin{align}
f(z) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^6 a_{7k+m} z^{7k+m-1} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^6 (3k + \lceil m/2 \rceil) z^{7k} z^m z^{-1} \\
&= z^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{7k} \sum_{m=0}^6 3k z^m + \lceil m/2 \rceil z^m \\
&= z^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{7k} \left( \frac{3k(z^7 - 1)}{z-1} + z + z^2 + 2z^3 + 2z^4 + 3z^5 + 3z^6\right) \\
&= \frac{3(z^7-1)}{z(z-1)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty k (z^7)^k + (1+z)(1+2z^2+3z^4) \sum_{k=0}^\infty (z^7)^k \\
&= \frac{3(z^7-1)}{z(z-1)} \left(\frac{z^7}{(1-z^7)^2} \right) + \frac{(1+z)(1+2z^2+3z^4)}{1-z^7} \\
&= \frac{1+z^2+z^4}{1-z-z^7+z^8}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun! The closed form  for

$$1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, \ldots$$

could be

$$a_n=n-\Big\lfloor{\frac n {\sqrt 3}}\Big\rfloor$$

according to [A195072](https://oeis.org/A195072)